# PHP delete values from Session Array

Tags: php, session

I want to delete some items from shopping cart, which is stored in a session variable named `$_SESSION["products"]`

The deleting part is working fine until there are different sizes of products with the same product code, when a request to delete is called for the specific size all the items gets deleted with that same product code.

Instead, it should only be deleted the item that is requested.

**This is my PHP code to delete**

```
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $product_size   = filter_var($_POST["product_size"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product size
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code && $cart_itm["size"]!=$product_size){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'size'=>$cart_itm["size"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }

        //create a new product list for cart
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

**Remove items from cart**

```
<span class="remove-itm">
<a href="'.$site_url.'/cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&size='.$cart_itm["size"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'" class="remove" title="Remove this product from cart"> &times;</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Your have to be carefull, do not change array, that you looping through in foreach. Change your code, use temp array to store the $products, instead of using $_SESSION["products"]. And move this line: `$_SESSION["products"] = $product;` out off the foreach body.

Comment: @StanislavTerletskyi Why? and how?

Comment: @StanislavTerletskyi i did move that line outside the foreach loop, but my problem its un resolved....

Comment: You should do refactoring for the condition. It can be less complicated. And You can use `$product[] = $cart_itm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $product_size   = filter_var($_GET["size"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product size
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url

    $product = array();

    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) 
    {

        if ($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code && $cart_itm["size"] == $product_size) 
        {
            // skip this product, it wont be saved in session
            continue;
        }
        // add this product
        $product[] = $cart_itm;
    }
    // save the updated product list
    $_SESSION["products"] = $product;

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

Comment: I've omitted some of your code, did you change only foreach part?

Comment: Hm, can you update your question and share the html part, only form.

Comment: Please check the updated question... to delete items I'm passing values through QueryStrings and then getting the values by GET method.

Comment: So maybe the problem in this part: `...filter_var($_POST["product_size"]...`
Here you get the value from $_POST array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80493/discussion-between-yaqoob-and-stanislav-terletskyi).

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$_SESSION["products"]` in each loop iteration. You need to move that outside of the loop:

```
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code && $cart_itm["size"]!=$product_size){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'size'=>$cart_itm["size"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }
    }

    //create a new product list for cart
    $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
```

Comment: its still deleting all the items with same product_code